# abp generate-proxy -t csharp -u http://127.0.0.1:12555 have error

Tags: abp

I But the following error occurs, I really don’t know what the problem is?
can anyone help me？
[image]

I have configed follow the link below
https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/7.1/API/Static-CSharp-API-Clients
(1) I have configed   typeof(AbpHttpClientModule) in client;
(2) I have configed  the following.
[image]
(3)I aslo added remote endpoint in application.Development.json.
[image]
(4)I Starupup the Server project.

and i run command in the following directory.
abp generate-proxy -t csharp -u http://127.0.0.1:12555

A previous error occurred.

ABP CLI 7.1.1

Answer (score 0):

The error is **The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing**

Please check the URL(http://127.0.0.1:12555/).

BTW, Let's discuss this on https://github.com/abpframework/abp/discussions/17934